# How to make a program show a toast instead of crashing?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on an app. Here's a small fragment which converts the entered string to a fraction:

```
public int[] fractionalize(String rawFraction1) {
        int[] result = {0,0,0};
        if (rawFraction1.contains("/") && !rawFraction1.contains(" ")){
            //normal fraction
            int a = Integer.parseInt(rawFraction1.split("/")[0]);
            int b = Integer.parseInt(rawFraction1.split("/")[1]);
            result = new int[]{a,b,0};
        } else if (rawFraction1.contains("/") && rawFraction1.contains(" ")){
            //mixed fraction
            int wholeNum = Integer.parseInt(rawFraction1.split(" ")[0]);
            int num = Integer.parseInt(rawFraction1.split(" ")[1].split("/")[0]);
            int den = Integer.parseInt(rawFraction1.split(" ")[1].split("/")[1]);
            result = new int[]{num, den, wholeNum};
        } else if (!rawFraction1.contains(" ") && !rawFraction1.contains("/")){
            int wholeNum = Integer.parseInt(rawFraction1);
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The number you entered is in an invalid format. Please see the correct format to enter numbers.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This works pretty well, provided you enter the number in the correct format. However, if we mess up the format, example, inserted 2 spaces or '/', the app crashes and closes. 
I want that if the program encounters a problem in this segment, it should show a toast instead and not close.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just surround it with try/catch as easy as:

```
    public int[] fractionalize(String rawFraction1) {
        try {
            int[] result = {0, 0, 0};
            if (rawFraction1.contains("/") && !rawFraction1.contains(" ")) {
                //normal fraction
                int a = Integer.parseInt(rawFraction1.split("/")[0]);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(rawFraction1.split("/")[1]);
                result = new int[]{a, b, 0};
            } else if (rawFraction1.contains("/") && rawFraction1.contains(" ")) {
                //mixed fraction
                int wholeNum = Integer.parseInt(rawFraction1.split(" ")[0]);
                int num = Integer.parseInt(rawFraction1.split(" ")[1].split("/")[0]);
                int den = Integer.parseInt(rawFraction1.split(" ")[1].split("/")[1]);
                result = new int[]{num, den, wholeNum};
            } else if (!rawFraction1.contains(" ") && !rawFraction1.contains("/")) {
                int wholeNum = Integer.parseInt(rawFraction1);
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The number you entered is in an invalid format. Please see the correct format to enter numbers.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Input.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I used this, but the app still crashes if i enter number in incorrect format....

Comment: What will this method return if it faces an error? Because if it doesn't return anything, the app will crash nonetheless.

Comment: it will return null if method failed. I do not have your full code but it seems like you should check if the method returns null.

Comment: Try use 
"return new int[]{0,0,0}"
 instead of "retrun null"

Answer (score 2):

You could check the string array length after splitting to show Toast.
Another solution is use try/catch, and in catch block you show Toast (not recommend)

Comment: I am new to this and so I don't know what the second option means. As for the first one, how would checking the string length help in this case?

Comment: for example, `rawFraction1.split("/")` return an array; you just need to check length of the array.